# How to write clojure documentation for a single function in a protocol?

Tags: clojure, documentation

Let's say I have a protocol like this:

```
(defprotocol X
  (y [this z]))
```

How do I write documentation targeted only for function `y`?

The normal way for doing this would be:

```
(defn y
  "Some documentation"
  [])
```

But if I do:

```
(defprotocol X
  (y
    "Some documentation" 
    [this z]))
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration missing
```

So how do I add this kind of documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defprotocol X
  (y [this z] "Some documentation"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find examples of a protocol on [clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defprotocol) :

```
(defprotocol Fly
  "A simple protocol for flying"
  (fly [this] "Method to fly"))
```

Alternatively bang your REPL or look at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core_deftype.clj#L672-L674) :

> ;method signatures
>
> ```
> (bar [this a b] \"bar docs\")
> (baz [this a] [this a b] [this a b c] \"baz docs\"))
> ```